# Extract a word from the string if the string contains a word from the list

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract a word from the string if the string contains a word from the list.

For example, there is string "RR_SM_Brand_A_Additive_Clean_jun2020",
and the list is Brand_A, Brand_B, Brand_C etc.

I use the following regex:

```
/^([\s\S]*?)(Brand_A|Brand_B|Brand_C)([\s\S]*?)$.*/m
```

Demo: [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xSgiLm/1)

It finds Brand_A but it also has some other groups. And when I run the corresponding query in Google BigQuery, I receive an error: *This query returned no results.*

```
SELECT distinct utm_campaign,  
REGEXP_EXTRACT(utm_campaign, r'/^([\s\S]*?)(Lysol|Airwick|Finish)([\s\S]*?)$.*/m')
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE utm_campaign = "RR_SM_Brand_A_Additive_Clean_jun2020"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the first and last parentheses with `(?: )` sets instead of `( )`.

```
/^(?:[\s\S]*?)(Brand_A|Brand_B|Brand_C)(?:[\s\S]*?)$.*/m
```

That will stop the parentheses from actually returning captured groups, making them grouping only, not capturing.